# Constructing a tangent line to a point on the curve $y = x^3$ using a compass and straight edge?

Tags: cubics, tangent-line, geometric-construction

There are number of ways of constructing a tangent line to the curve $y = x^2$ using a compass and straight edge. Does anyone know of a way of constructing a tangent line to the curve $y = x^3$ using a compass and straight edge?

Comment: what would you need a compass for?

Comment: Finding the mid point of a line segment or doubling the length of a line segment.

Comment: also for constructing parallel lines

Comment: Are we supposed to assume we know where the coordinate axes are? Or at least the $y$ axis? Since it's possible to identify a conic from five points we can find the axis of the parabola but it's easier if we already know where it is, or at least have a line parallel to it. If you would include one of your constructions for the tangent to $y=x^2$ in the question, it would help clarify what assumptions we are allowed to make.

Comment: I asked the question because I wanted to know if this problem had already been solved. I have been thinking about this problem for three years and I just found a way to do it when only the graph is given! Proving the general validity of the construction is beyond my capabilities but in geogebra I have found it yields exact tangent lines for numerous cases including some graphs of the form y=ax^3+bx^2 + cx + d.

Answer (score 2):

This a solution to my own question. I am the source. I have not been able to find a solution in the literature.The construction can be validated by anyone using a geometry program like geogebra.

Compass and Straightedge method for constructing a tangent to a Cubic $y = ax^3 +bx^2+cx + d$  at point $A$. The blue line $AL$ is the required tangent.

Note: the method does not work if point A is at the point of inflection.
I did not include all the steps requiring a compass as this would clutter the animation.

NEW ...Inaddition to the first animation, I added two more animations. The second one shows a construction for finding the point of inflection and the vertical axis. The third shows a construction for finding the tangent line (in blue) through a point on the curve as well as the tangent line (in magenta) through the point of inflection when the point of inflection and the vertical axis have already been determined.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I clarified that I am the source of this answer. I have not been able to find a solution in the literature.

Comment: Apologies: where is  your copy and paste image in "your answer" from?

Comment: I created the graphic and uploaded it.

Comment: Thanks! I see you added "geogebra", also, in your answer.

Comment: Geogebra didn't pose the problem and it didn't find the solution, but of course it is a great to tool for rapidly exploring and testing numerous constructions. Dynamic geometry programs like geogebra enable users to formulate new kinds of questions about compass and straightedge constructions that may never have occurred to the geometers of antiquity.

Comment: I think I was able to follow and reproduce your method in geogebra. It might be useful to summarize the main steps in the question (not every single operation, but at least the sequence of steps that are shown in your animation).

Comment: A key fact appears to be that the line $DG$ is parallel to the $y$ axis. So this answers the question about knowing the axes: we do not need to know them in advance.

Comment: @Euclid_Looked_On_Beauty_Bare Some colleagues of mine are writing a paper on areas bounded by polynomials and would love to refer to your construction of the point of inflection. Are you planning to write this up formally as a paper? If you would like to reach out directly to one of the authors, their email is listed in the About section of my Profile page.

Comment: @adamglesser Thank you for your interest. I would call myself an amateur geometer. My formal mathematical education ended 35 years  ago when I completed a 3year BSc in physics at university. I have never published anything in a journal so I would be very happy to have my work mentioned in your paper.  Over the last 15 years I developed an interest in tangent constructions to curves using a compass and straight edge. In the course of my explorations I discovered many other tangents constructions for certain third and fourth degree curves which I think are novel.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you are given the graph of $y = x^3$ plotted in a Cartesian coordinate system and an arbitrary point on the graph, and you are to construct a line tangent to the graph at that point without using any knowledge of the location of the origin of the coordinates or the orientation of the axes.

You have already given a valid construction, so this answer will focus on how we can prove it is valid.

The construction uses the following fact:

> If $A$, $B$, and $C$ are three distinct points on the curve $y = x^3$ with $x$-coordinates $x_A$, $x_B$, and $x_C$ respectively, then $A$, $B$, and $C$ are collinear if and only if $x_A + x_B + x_C = 0.$

Proof of "only if": suppose $A$, $B$, and $C$ are collinear. Let $y = ax + b$ be the equation of the line on which the three points lie.
Then the cubic polynomial $x^3 - ax - b$ has distinct roots at $x_A$, $x_B$, and $x_C$,
and therefore $x^3 - ax - b = (x - x_A)(x - x_B)(x - x_C)$.
Multiplying out the expression on the right and setting coefficients of the polynomials on both sides equal, we find that the coefficient of $x^2$ on the right is
$-(x_A + x_B + x_C)$
whereas the coefficient on the left is $0$, so $x_A + x_B + x_C = 0.$

Proof of "if": Suppose $x_A + x_B + x_C = 0.$
Let $y = ax + b$ be the equation of the line on which the points $A$ and $B$ lie.
Then the cubic polynomial $x^3 - ax - b$ has roots at $x_A$, $x_B$, and some value $x_0$, and therefore $x^3 - ax - b = (x - x_A)(x - x_B)(x - x_0)$
and $x_A + x_B + x_0 = 0.$ Therefore $x_0 = -x_A - x_B = x_C.$
This implies that the line $AB$ intersects the curve $y = x^3$ at a point $P$ with $x$-coordinate $x_C$.
But since $y = x^3$ is the graph of a function of $x$, there is only one point on the curve with $x$-coordinate $x_C$, namely $C$.
Hence the line $AB$ intersects the curve at $C$ and the three points are collinear.

We also use the following fact:

> If $A$ and $B$ are distinct points on the curve $y=x^3$ with $x$-coordinates $x_A$ and $x_B$ respectively, then the line $AB$ is tangent to the curve at $B$ if and only if $x_A + 2x_B = 0.$

The proof is similar to the previous proof, except that in the "only if" direction we assume the polynomial $x^3 - ax - b$ has a double root at $x_B$, whereas in the "if" direction we have to prove $x_B$ is a double root.

---

For ease of exposition, in the following I will write $x_P$ to denote the $x$ coordinate of point $P$, where the letter $P$ can be replaced by the name of any point.

Then the construction works as follows.

Let an arbitrary point $A$ on the curve $y = x^3$ be given,
with the condition only that $A$ is not the point $(0,0).$

Find a line $ABC$ that intersects the curve in two other points $B$ and $C$.
Therefore $x_A + x_B + x_C = 0$.
Let $D$ be the midpoint of $B$ and $C$; then
$x_D = \frac12(x_B + x_C) = -\frac12 x_A$.

Similarly, find a different line $AEF$ intersecting the curve at two other points $E$ and $F$. Therefore $x_A + x_E + x_F = 0$.
Let $G$ be the midpoint of $E$ and $F$; then
$x_G = \frac12(x_E + x_F) = -\frac12 x_A$.

Therefore $x_G = -\frac12 x_A = x_D$ and the line $DG$ is the line
$x = -\frac12 x_A$.
(Note that the $x$-coordinates of $D$ and $G$ are not only equal,
but they are derived by essentially the same procedure.)

Construct the line $AH$ through $A$ parallel to $DG$. Therefore $x_H = x_A$.
Take a point $I$ on the curve distinct from $A$.
Reflect the point $I$ through $H$ to produce the point $J$.
Therefore $x_I + x_J = 2x_H = 2x_A.$
Construct a line through $J$ parallel to $AH$, intersecting the curve at $K$.
Then $x_K = x_J$ and $x_I + x_K = 2x_A.$
If the line $IK$ intersects the curve at a third point $L$,
then $x_L = -2x_A.$
(If there is not a third intersection, you have chosen $I$ so that $IK$ is tangent to the curve; try a different point $I$.)

Now construct the line $AL$. Since $x_L + 2x_A = 0,$ this line is tangent to the curve $y = x^3$ at $A.$

---

Note that I specified that $A$ is not the point $(0,0)$ in the proof of the construction. If $A$ is $(0,0)$ then all lines through $A$ that intersect the curve in two other points intersect the curve in points that are symmetric about $A$.
Therefore if we attempt to follow the construction as described, we will find that
$D = G = A$.
Therefore the points $D$ and $G$ do not determine a line.

This is an easily resolved difficulty, because we can simply start the construction at some point other than $A$ in order to find a line parallel to the $y$ axis.
The real difficulty is that the tangent at $A$ does not pass through any other point on the curve, so we cannot construct a distinct point $L$ on the curve that determines the tangent line.

If we suppose that we are able to detect that $A$ is the midpoint of $B$ and $C$,
then we could construct a line through $A$ parallel to the $y$ axis, then a line through $A$ perpendicular to the first line.
But I'm not aware that the standard toolbox of compass-and-straightedge constructions includes the ability to recognize that you have arrived exactly at a previously given point.

---

The construction for the curve $y = x^3$ generalizes to a construction for
$y = p(x)$ for any cubic polynomial $p(x)$,
provided that $A$ is not at the inflection point of the curve,
because the graph of $y = p(x)$ is simply a translation of a linear transformation of the graph of $y = x^3$, and the essential steps of the construction
(the pairs of parallel lines and the proportional positions of the named points along the named lines)
are all preserved by linear transformations and by translations.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed proof. It will take me some time to fully digest it. How do you know the x value at points D and G are the same?



When just the graph of a cubic curve is given I have now figured out how to
1) find the point of inflection with a construction.
2) construct the tangent through the point of inflection
3) use the results of 1 and 2  to construct a tangent to any other point.

Comment: We get the x-coordinate of G essentially the same way as the x-coordinate of D. I have made the steps for G more explicit. Since this procedure produces a line parallel to the $y$ axis and produces points with $x$-coordinates $x_A$ and $-2x_A,$ it is not hard to find a point at $x=0$ and use a parallel line construction to construct the $y$ axis, which then intersects $y=x^3$ at the inflection point. This construction also is preserved by linear transformation and translation, so it works for any cubic. But I haven't worked out a tangent at the inflection point for every cubic.

Comment: Maybe it is obvious, but for three points to be collinear don't you need to work with both the y and x values for each point?

Comment: The equation $y=ax+b$ (where $a$ and $b$ are constants) is the equation of a line. So if the $(x,y)$ coordinates of two or more points all satisfy the equation $y=ax + b$, then the points are collinear. If you think I have neglected a coordinate somewhere you will have to ask about the missing coordinate more specifically; I can't guess which one you mean.

Comment: I am approaching it like this https://www.math-only-math.com/conditions-of-collinearity-of-three-points.html .

Comment: That's an interesting exercise but it's horrible as a recommendation for a general-purpose technique to determine collinearity. Before studying cubic equations you should already know that $y=ax+b$ is an equation of a line.

Comment: When I think about the problem from a construction standpoint, I see the line $y=ax+b$ intersects the curve $y=x^3$ in three points and each point is an ordered pair of values (x,y). In other words I know the three points must be collinear, so the problem is to determine the points of intersection. You begin with a different assumption where the points aren't collinear and then find a condition which makes them collinear.

Comment: I thought the cubic formula would be essential but your proof is algebraically much simpler. However, I am finding it harder to follow the reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

We know that $\frac d{dx}x^3 = 3x^2$.  Thus, when you have a point $(x,x^3)$ on the graph, it's easy to go 1 unit to the right and $3x^2$ units up — provided we have the $y$-axis and know how wide 1 unit is (and assuming we are on a cartesian grid with the same scaling of $x$ and $y$.

This means when we habe $y=x^3$ drawn, say, on some paper, we have to

1. Find the symmetry point $(x=y=0)$.
2. Find the line $x=0$ and $y=0$.
3. Find the point $x=y=1$.

No 3. is easy once we have 2. because we find $(1,1)$ by intersecting the graph with the angle bisector $y=x$ of the $x$- and $y$-axes.  Likewise, if we have 1. and 3. then it's easy to find 2.

As we have only the graph any nothing else (at least that's what the question is implying as only the graph is mentioned and no coordinate lines or special points), all we can do is picking 2 points $P$ and $Q$ on the graph at random and to construct the 3rd points $R$ which lies on the line through $P$ and $Q$. This reminds of the group law on elliptic curves.  However, I don't see a way to reach $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$ in a finite number of steps.  The coordinates are random, an all we know is that with almost certainty the quotient $x_P/x_Q$ is transcendental.

And btw. I don't see how it would for a parabola, except you have already given points with given known, rational quotient of the points' coordinates.

Comment: I am not asking how to construct a tangent to a point on an unidentified graph. In order for me to assert a graph is y=x^3, I must be aware of information about the graph even if I did not supply the information. Therefore you are free, figuratively speaking, to fill in the blanks.

Comment: @Euclid Looked On Beauty Bare: I don't understand what you are saying.  Either you have that additional extra information like where the coordinate axes are located, or you don't.  It makes a crucial difference.  If you have that information, then it's straight forward to construct tangents at given point; if the information is not available then you are stuck.

Comment: I have been thinking about this problem for three years. At first I thought some supplemental information was also required, but  I just discovered there is way to do it if only the graph is given! Furthermore I think it works for any graph of the form y = ax^3+ bx^2+ cx+d. However, proving the general validity of the construction is beyond my capabilities but I have checked numerous variations in geogebra and in each case the construction yields an exact tangent line.

Comment: @Euclid Looked On Beauty Bare: Presumably, in geogebra you are using knowledge about the lines $y=0$ and $x=0$ and are using these for construction, maybe without giving credit to it... As I said, when you have the coordinate axes given, then the construction is straight forward.

Comment: At first I thought I was relying on them, but when you asked the question it made me realised that I was not. I first became interested in this problem three years ago. I asked the question because I wanted to know if this problem had already been solved.

Comment: @Euclid Looked On Beauty Bare: So why don't you post that solution for verification in the first place? It's a bit ominous asking questions when one knows the answer...

Comment: I would like to believe it is a small but novel contribution to geometry so I want to make sure the problem has not already been solved. I am also leery about posting anything novel on this site as I may lose credit.